# How to check exactly duplicate object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am javascript beginner and I want to check exactly duplicate object in array
like this

`array = [{name: 'Tom', email: 'Tom@gmail.com'},{name: 'Pete', email: 'Pete@gmail.com'}]`

and then I have object `object = {name: 'Tom', email: 'Tom@gmail.com'}`

when I push object to array like `array.push(object)`

I want to check if object is exactly duplicate (same value in every key) object in array (array[0])

How to ?

Comment: Please provide [Minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ProgrammingRage No, I want to push object into array if in array not exist object like the one I want to push

Comment: Do not push the object into the array until all validation is successful. If any validation fails then just print that it is a duplicate or do whatever you intend to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using `Set`

- Create a `Set` and concatenate all values with some separator string that you're sure doesn't appear in your values (I've chosen `+`).
- So, for this object `{ name: "Tom", email: "Tom@gmail.com" }` we store `Tom+Tom@gmail.com` in the `Set`.
- Now, while pushing again concatenate all values with the same separator string and check if this exists in the `Set`.

  - If it does, don't push
  - Otherwise push it to the array.

I've tried to push two objects in the snippet below, the first object doesn't get pushed while the second does.

#### Caveat

- Suppose you have an object where is `name` is `"Tom+"` and `email` is `"Tom@gmail.com"` (`{ name: "Tom", email: "Tom@gmail.com" }`).
- So we store `"Tom++Tom@gmail.com"` in the `Set`
- Now suppose we want to insert an object where `name` is `Tom` and `email` is `+Tom@gmail.com`, which is definitely a different object from the one above.
- But since we again generate the same string `Tom++Tom@gmail.com` to check in the `Set`, we don't push this object onto the array.

**So, it is essential to choose the separator string wisely.**

```js
const 
  arr = [{ name: "Tom", email: "Tom@gmail.com" }, { name: "Pete", email: "Pete@gmail.com" }],
      
  s = new Set(arr.map((o) => Object.values(o).join("+"))),

  addNewObj = (arr, obj) => {
    if (!s.has(Object.values(obj).join("+"))) {
      arr.push(obj);
    }
  };

addNewObj(arr, { name: "Tom", email: "Tom@gmail.com" });
addNewObj(arr, { name: "John", email: "John@gmail.com" });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @Marimokung Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.